# language server protocol: sync at editor start-up

Tags: language-server-protocol

I'm implementing both client and server side for LSP.

I'd like to follow the protocol as strictly as possible.

When I start my editor (the client) it should inform the server what the local code base looks like right now, (a git sha plus some changes since most-recent-common-ancestor,) so that the server can answer correctly when I e.g. go-to-definition.

How do you do that in LSP?

I know I can send a `textDocument/didChange` for each document which has changes since most-recent-common-ancestor.

But how can the server send its current git SHA to the client, and how can the client send the most-recent-common-ancestor to the server? As far as I can see, this information is needed, but not part of the Langserver Protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LSP is currently designed with the assumption that both the LSP client and server can access the same filesystem - for which such "sync" operations are not necessary. It also doesn't assume anything about SCM or Git (which is fair as most of the code written isn't necessarily in a Git repository).

You can add extensions to the protocol to let the client (IDE or editor) send a "snapshot" of the project on startup, but it would become both server and client specific integration, diminishing the value of using LSP.